# Flutter- Passing Data between Custom Widgets inside column

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm stuck with a `WidgetA()` which calculates a String but I'd like to pass this string to `WidgetB()` - how do I pass the updated data to `WidgetB` ?

```
return Column(
  children: [
    
         WidgetA() // calculates value
         WidgetB() // needs to use this value 

  ],
);
```

Widget A is a costum Class Stateful Widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious way, to me, to do this is to store the data in the state of the parent widget. You could then provide `WidgetA` with a callback to set this state, and provide `WidgetB` with the value:

```dart
int value;

setValue(int newValue) {
    setState(() {
      value = newValue;
    });
}

return Column(
  children: [
    
         WidgetA(callback: (int newValue) => this.setValue(newValue)) // calculates value
         WidgetB(value: this.value) // needs to use this value 

  ],
);
```

WidgetA and WidgetB could then look something like the following:

```dart
class WidgetA extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function callback;

  // get the callback as a named argument
  WidgetA({required this.callback});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print('The button was pressed!');
          // get the value and call the callback with it
          callback(42);
        },
        child: Text('Press me!'));
  }
}

class WidgetB extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;

  WidgetB({required this.value});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('The number is $value');
  }
}
```

Depending on the value and how often it's updated, using some sort of storage like [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) for the value is also possible.

Comment: you also need to call setState in setValue method after setting value

Comment: I just realised that myself too, and updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi thank you very much - how do I create the callback in Widget A?

Comment: this does not work I get "The argument type 'dynamic Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'."

Comment: (int newValue) => this.setValue(newValue)

Comment: I added examples for `WidgetA` and `WidgetB`. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Ok it works thank you I added widget.callback(42)

Comment: but how do I do it with shared preferences ?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the [package on pub](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) or having a look elsewhere online [like this medium post](https://suragch.medium.com/saving-and-reading-data-in-flutter-with-sharedpreferences-bb4238d3105). There should be plenty of resources available. I think using the state is a great way to do it unless you want to preserve the value after an app restart

Comment: And if the answer solves your problem you can mark it as the correct solution ;)

Comment: I'd like to send this value to firebase for my personal calendar : ) should I write it to a data model file or is this way okay ?

Comment: I'd like the data to persist even if view is rebuilt if it is possible (I don't need it to persist through restart)

Comment: The state persists over rebuilds, so that should be fine. If you don't need it after a restart there's no use storing it in shared preferences or some other local database/file.

Comment: I switch between 2 views one widget up so I guess I have to do another call back to the other parent widget so it is temporary stored there ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared memory, for example, a class, and save the value to a class variable.

```
class SharedMemory {
      String stringCalculatedByWidgetA;
}
```

Then make sure that WidgetB updates the value in the shared memory.

Comment: Is this shared preferences ?

Comment: No, it is not "shared preferences".These values are lost, when the application is restarted.